# Lazy loading not working with Angular-cli webpack

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to lazy load one module getting same issue:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin'

I am using:

`angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3
node: 6.7.0
os: win32 x64`

**"ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16",**

*package.json*

`"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16",
    "ng2-sidebar": "^1.6.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",
    "codelyzer": "1.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }`

**app.routing.ts**

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
    canLoad: [LoginAuth]
  }
];

const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  ...loginRoutes,
  ...adminRoutes
];


export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [..],
  imports: [...,ng2Components,routing,LoginModule],
  providers: [LoginService, LoginAuth],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**admin.routing.ts**

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [LoginAuth],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'admin',
        canActivateChild: [LoginAuth],
        children: [
          {path: 'users', component: UserComponent},
          {path: 'dashboard', component: AdminDashboardComponent},
          {path: '', redirectTo: '/admin/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

export const adminRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes);
```

If I am importing AdminModule in @NgModule then it's working fine, but in that case LazyLoading will not work what should I do?

I also tried [following workaround](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2496#issuecomment-260105240) but it's still not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was making mistake here

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [LoginAuth],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'admin', // <<<<<<<<=========== here it should like this: '' not this 'admin'
        canActivateChild: [LoginAuth],
        children: [
          {path: 'users', component: UserComponent},
          {path: 'dashboard', component: AdminDashboardComponent},
          {path: '', redirectTo: '/admin/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**Doing this its working for me**

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [LoginAuth],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        canActivateChild: [LoginAuth],
        children: [
          {path: 'users', component: UserComponent},
          {path: 'dashboard', component: AdminDashboardComponent},
          {path: '', redirectTo: '/admin/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Got same error after migrating from SystemJS to angular cli webpack. We were using barrels (index.ts) to import our components across our code base. Webpack doesn't seem to support this. If you are using any barrels, try to avoid it and try importing the components directly. I hope this helps.

For reference : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1585

Comment: yes i am using index.ts to import my component, let me do that first than i will let you know

Comment: i have removed index.ts and imported my components directly but its not working. still i am getting Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin'

Comment: I tried to dig the issue by adding a break point in the js code that is reporting this error. Probably you could do that and have a watch on the params/variables in that context. For me, the component that was to be loaded was undefined.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and even though everything was correct the module wasn't being loaded when try to navigate there. You just need to update your CLI

```
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```